# Traducir la sintaxis de oracle a mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle

Tengo este fragmento el cual esta hecho solo para funcionar en oracle, me pidieron que lo pasara a funciones de mysql pero no se como hacerlo, lo del sql es lo menos importante, pero la verdad no se que "funciones" equivalen lo mismo en oracle que en mysql, por ejemplo oci_bind_by_name

```
$conexion = oci_connect('PROYECTO','presariocq43','localhost/XE');
            $sql="UPDATE PACIENTE SET NOMBRE=:NOMBRE,APELLIDO=:APELLIDO,
                TELEFONO=:TELEFONO,CORREO=:CORREO,DIRECCION=:DIRECCION,
                EDAD=:EDAD WHERE CEDULA=:CEDULA";
            $q = oci_parse ($conexion,$sql);
                #Aquí se pasan los valores de forma segura
                oci_bind_by_name($q, ":CEDULA", $CEDULA);
                oci_bind_by_name($q, ":NOMBRE", $NOMBRE);
                oci_bind_by_name($q, ":APELLIDO", $APELLIDO);
                oci_bind_by_name($q, ":TELEFONO", $TELEFONO);
                oci_bind_by_name($q, ":CORREO", $CORREO);
                oci_bind_by_name($q, ":DIRECCION", $DIRECCION);
                oci_bind_by_name($q, ":EDAD", $EDAD);
                #Verificamos si no hay error en la ejecución
            if (oci_execute($q)) {
                echo ' Se actualizo correctamente';
            }else {
                echo 'No se pudo actualizar';
            }
            break;
```

Comment: Busca sobre PDO en PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para MySQL hay dos APIs, una es `PDO` que sirve además para cualquier gestor de base de datos,  la otra API es `mysqli`.

Te voy a mostrar el código migrado usando ambas APIs.

## PDO

`PDO` es una clase, por lo tanto tienes que usar obligatoriamente el estilo orientado a objetos. Esto no es un inconveniente sino un avance porque este estilo es más moderno y más claro.

Veamos primero el equivalente de cada cosa, en la parte de la derecha tienes los enlaces del Manual de PHP para que estudies cada una a fondo, hay detalles a aprender para una práctica óptima:

- `oci_connect()` ... [`new PDO ()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.connections.php)
- `oci_parse()`   ... [`prepare()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) <sup>1</sup>
- `oci_bind_by_name()` ... [`bindParam()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php) <sup>2</sup>
- `oci_execute()` ... [`execute()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php)

### Código migrado a PDO para MySQL

> **IMPORTANTE**: Revisa [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.connections.php) para saber cómo construir el DSN para MySQL. En el caso de PDO por seguridad hay que apagar las
>   preparaciones emuladas y un manejo adecuado de errores. Eso lo haremos pasando un 4º parámetro en forma de array. Y conviene también indicar un charset
>   adecuado, sobre todo cuando trabajas con palabras acentuadas o `ñ` en
>   los datos.

```
#Cambiar cada variable por lo que corresponda:
$host="localhost";
$dbname="nombreBaseDeDatos";
$user="usuario";
$pass="password";
$charset="utf8";
$options = array(
                  PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE, 
                  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
           );

#No cambies nada en los parámetros de new, cámbialo en las variables

$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=$charset", $user, $pass, $options);
            $sql="UPDATE PACIENTE SET NOMBRE=:NOMBRE,APELLIDO=:APELLIDO,
                TELEFONO=:TELEFONO,CORREO=:CORREO,DIRECCION=:DIRECCION,
                EDAD=:EDAD WHERE CEDULA=:CEDULA";
            $q = $conexion->prepare ($sql);
                #Aquí se pasan los valores de forma segura
                #En PDO se indica el tipo de dato en un tercer parámetro (ver nota 2 y enlace)

                $q->bindParam(":CEDULA", $CEDULA, PDO::PARAM_INT); #¿Es numérico?
                $q->bindParam(":NOMBRE", $NOMBRE, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $q->bindParam(":APELLIDO", $APELLIDO, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $q->bindParam(":TELEFONO", $TELEFONO, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $q->bindParam(":CORREO", $CORREO, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $q->bindParam(":DIRECCION", $DIRECCION, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $q->bindParam(":EDAD", $EDAD, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                #Verificamos si no hay error en la ejecución
            if ($q->execute()) {
                echo "Se actualizaron correctamente {$q->rowCount()}  filas";
            }else {
                echo "No se pudo actualizar";
            }
```

---

## mysqli

Tiene dos estilos. Uno procedural (que es medio rollo para mi gusto) y otro orientado a objetos que es parecido a PDO.

Me voy basar en el estilo orientado a objetos por razones de brevedad. Si te interesa el estilo procedural, una vez entendida la migración será fácil hacerlo.

Veamos primero el equivalente de cada cosa, en la parte de la derecha tienes los enlaces del Manual de PHP para que estudies cada una a fondo, hay detalles a aprender para una práctica óptima:

- `oci_connect()` ... [`new mysqli ()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php)
- `oci_parse()`   ... [`prepare()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) <sup>3</sup>
- `oci_bind_by_name()` ... [`bind_param()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) <sup>4</sup>
- `oci_execute()` ... [`execute()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)

### Código migrado a `mysqli` para MySQL

```
#Cambiar cada variable por lo que corresponda:
$host="localhost";
$dbname="nombreBaseDeDatos";
$user="usuario";
$pass="password";
$charset="utf8";

#No cambies nada en los parámetros de new, cámbialo en las variables

$conexion = new mysqli($localhost, $user, $pass, $database);
$conexion->set_charset($charset);
            #OJO a los marcadores, son de posición y no hay :
            $sql="UPDATE PACIENTE SET NOMBRE=?,APELLIDO=?,
                TELEFONO=?,CORREO=?,DIRECCION=?,
                EDAD=? WHERE CEDULA=?";
            $q = $conexion->prepare ($sql);
                #Aquí se pasan los valores de forma segura
                #En mysqli se indica el tipo de dato con iniciales predefinidas y los datos separados por coma
                #Ver nota 4 y enlace
                #Aquí i: significa un dato numérico y s: un dato string
                #adapta cada uno a tu tipo de dato
                #OJO: las variables deben pasarse en el orden respectivo de los marcadores ?
                #en la consulta preparada más arriba
                $q->bind_param("isssssi", $CEDULA, $NOMBRE, $APELLIDO, $TELEFONO, $CORREO, $DIRECCION, $EDAD);
                #Verificamos si no hay error en la ejecución
            if ($q->execute()) {
                echo "Se actualizaron correctamente {$q->affected_rows}  filas";
            }else {
                echo "No se pudo actualizar";
            }
```

---

## P.D.:

Eso es todo. No he probado el código, no creo haber cometido errores graves. Con eso tu código queda migrado a MySQL.

---

## Notas

1. PDO admite marcadores de `:nombre` o marcadores de posición `?`
2. En PDO, si se usa `bindParam()` se indica el tipo de dato usando constantes predefinidas ([ver aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.constants.php)). Los datos se pueden pasar alternativamente como array en el `execute()`. En ese caso no se indica el tipo de dato.
3. **IMPORTANTE:** `mysqli` **no usa marcadores de nombre**, sólo de posición `?`
4. La forma de pasar los parámetros y el tipo de dato es diferente a PDO. Aquí se pasa una cadena con los tipos de dato y una lista con los valores. Por ejemplo: `("sis",$valor1, $valor2, $valor3)`. Ver el apartado [*Especificación del tipo de caracteres*  en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).